# 'AnsiConsole' does not contain a definition for 'Live'

Tags: c#, nuget, console-application, spectre.console

I am using [***Spectre.Console***](https://spectreconsole.net/) extension for **<kbd>C#</kbd> <kbd>Console Application</kbd>**. And I wanted to use [**Live-Display**](https://spectreconsole.net/live/live-display) module of ***Spectre.Console*** but I encoutered following problem:

`'AnsiConsole' does not contain a definition for 'Live'`

> Here is my code, or better say, part of it which contains problem (<kbd>**...**</kbd> are parts which aren't required in sample, so during testing/debugging/modification remove them)

```cs
using System;
using Spectre.Console;
...

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        ...
        static void Main(...)
        {
            AnsiConsole.Live(Clock())
                .Start(ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Refresh();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                });
            ...
        }
        ...
        public static void Clock()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

> Additional information

- I installed extension using <kbd>NuGet</kbd> package manager with following command: `PM> Install-Package Spectre.Console`, not with `dotnet add package Spectre.Console` as indicated in docs, but latter option was unavailable for some reason so I used first.
- I am using **Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition**
- I am using **.NET Framework 4.7.2**

Comment: Which version of Spectre.Console are you using? The Live method was only added 5 days ago by the looks of it.

Comment: It's definitely not in the stable assemblies (0.39).

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using **latest stable**. Don't remember exactly which but I think it was **0.39**

Comment: @yaakov So I need to install pre-release?

Comment: @JonSkeet and @yaakov! Because of your mentions and comments I found out what was problem (it was version difference) and now my code is working. Big thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to [@JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s and [@yaakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1994390/yaakov)'s comments, I tried installing <kbd>**latest pre-release version**</kbd> *0.39.1-preview-0.31* instead of <kbd>**latest stable version**</kbd> *0.39* and it worked.

Looks like problem was with versions.